# IE11 (windows phone 8.1) not sensing (displaying the dimensions of) screen rotation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, windows-phone-8.1, screen-rotation

I'm creating a website using bootstrap and jquery and I was testing it for both desktop/mobile. Through javascript I had to modify some elements in the DOM, otherwise the layout would have been too messy.
Using my Lumia 735 (WindowsPhone 8.1 GDR1) with IE11 I noticed that the screen rotation is not really "sensed" by the browser.
To do so I added a simple code in the page (as follows) and tried to load and reload the page many times with both orientations, but only portrait dimensions are displayed

```
<div id="screenDimensions"></div>

<script>
/*set of parameters*/
var screenHeight =
    window.screen.height;
var screenWidth = 
    window.screen.width; 

/*creation of the function that shows you the screen dimensions*/
function writeDimensions(){
/*change of the values in the parameters*/
    screenHeight =
        window.screen.height;
    screenWidth = 
        window.screen.width; 

    /*change of the content of the div screenDimensions*/
    document.getElementById('screenDimensions').innerHTML=
    ("<strong>width: " 
            +screenWidth 
            +", height: "
            +screenHeight
            +"</strong>" 
            );
}

/*execute the function once when the page is ready*/
$(document).ready(function(){
    writeDimensions();
})

/*and do it again when you sense a resize in the browser dimensions*/
$(window).resize(function(){
        writeDimensions();
    })
</script>
```

My question is: **is there a way to let the browser (on a mobile device/tablet) sense the rotation? Otherwise, is there a way to optimize the layout for small screen?**

Edit. After further test I discovered that the rotation is sensed by CSS (see following code), but the Javascript (that has been updated too as above) keep not working.

In the footer I added (this way you'll always have a coloured strip that should change its colour when you rotate the screen)

```
<div id="testdiv">
    <strong>Color case</strong>
</div>
```

with the following CSS rules:

```
#testdiv{
    background-color:#3399FF; //blue, default colour
}

@media only screen and (max-width:1080px){
    #testdiv{
        background-color:#99FF99; //light green
    }
}
@media only screen and (max-width:768px){
    #testdiv{
        background-color:#CC00CC; //purple
    }
}
@media only screen and (max-width:600px){ //random value
    #testdiv{
        background-color:#00CC00; //green
    }
}
@media only screen and (max-width:450px){ //random value
    #testdiv{
        background-color:#996633; //brown
    }
}
```

The question is the same as before, and I add this one: **on desktop the javascript that is above works, on mobile no. The CSS instead works at it should. Why?**

Answer (score 0):

Try following instead of $(window).resize(function(){}

```
var mql = window.matchMedia("(orientation: portrait)");

// If there are matches, we're in portrait
if(mql.matches) {  
   // Portrait orientation
 } else {  
  // Landscape orientation
 }

 // Add a media query change listener
  mql.addListener(function(m) {
  if(m.matches) {
    // Changed to portrait
  }
  else {
    // Changed to landscape
  }
 });
```

Comment: Nice one, I tried your code adding a simple to print the orientation and it seems to work. I can't say the same thing for the screen dimensions. I've just tried with the Lumia 735, an iPad Air 2 and a Samsung Galaxy S5 and the results are quite different.
On Lumia 735 and iPad Air 2 the screen dimensions don't change at all, on Samsumg Galaxy S5 the dimensions change but only after 2 rotations, and they display the previous values (so if we're in portrait, they will display the landscape values if you have rotated for at least 2 times the screen).
Any idea about how to fix this?

Comment: Can you send me sample file code on my id: pradeep07us@gmail.com ?

Comment: Sorry for the late answer, I've been away the last days. However the code used is all there in the first post, I haven't changed it since last week... But if you still need a sample code of the entire page let me know